# Cast Exception - AndroidJUnitRunner cannot be cast to RoboMonitoringInstrumentation

Tags: android, android-testing

Working on Android Instrumented Test to launch and test this fragment

[image]

But I am running to this nasty error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner cannot be cast to org.robolectric.android.fakes.RoboMonitoringInstrumentation
at org.robolectric.android.internal.LocalActivityInvoker.getInstrumentation(LocalActivityInvoker.java:153)
at org.robolectric.android.internal.LocalActivityInvoker.startActivity(LocalActivityInvoker.java:40)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launchInternal(ActivityScenario.java:265)
at androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario.launch(ActivityScenario.java:226)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$Companion.internalLaunch$fragment_testing_release(FragmentScenario.kt:588)
at androidx.fragment.app.testing.FragmentScenario$Companion.launchInContainer(FragmentScenario.kt:559)
at com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.taskdetail.TaskDetailFragmentTest.activeTasks_displayedInUi(TaskDetailFragmentTest.kt:35)Tests ran to completion.
```

These are the dependencies that I'm using

[image]

Have been looking for an answer online but I have not come to any useful finding.

What could I be missing?

Comment: Here is my link for the project https://github.com/Tonnie-Dev/android-testing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the Roboelectric Dependency and ensure it is **testImplementation**

In my case I was using this version

```
implementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.5.1
```

The error was gone when I switched to test implementation.

```
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:4.5.1"
```

Comment: And I will also add, Robolectric can not be used in `androidTestImplementation` source set either - you're gonna get the exactly same mysteriours error message. It's so easy to make a mistake accidentally adding depedencies for the wrong source set, and so hard to solve them :)